# Changing the Length of The Google Custom Search Snippet

Tags: google-custom-search, information-extraction, google-rich-snippets

I am using Google Custom Search API for querying the web for specific text patterns. Hence, I'm basically interested in the 'snippet' of each returned result. The problem is, the current length of the 'snippet' field of the JSON result of any query is limited to 160 characters, and I sometimes need more context for the matched query than that. I was wondering if there is any way for extending the length of the snippet.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

There is not. Google (and all other search engines) keep the size of snippets short for many reasons.

If you search query uses the double quotes signs `"`, and a URL is returned, fetch that URL and do your matching then.